# How to capture the words between M/S but without the last uniqueid

Tags: c#, regex

How to capture only a part of the following. 
The capture should be restricted to what is between M/S and the UniqueID.
My Regex `(?<=M\/S\s)((\w+)?\s)+(?=(U|$))` captures the lines with UniqueID but not the lines without the UniqueId. Could anyone guide me please?

```
$0117578$ $0003123$ ADECBR5148K M/S R A MARKETING PRIVATE LIMITED
$0117942$ $0003487$ ADECBR6540D M/S RICHDAUGHTER KURIES AND INVESTMENTS PVT LIMITED
$0117856$ $0003401$ ADEBCR7789P M/S REGENT TRADING CO
$0117881$ $0003426$ ADEBCR1123M M/S RELIANT MARKETING AND SERVICES PVT LTD  U53599KL1989PTC000007
$0117896$ $0003441$ ADECBR7750D M/S GANDHIMARG CHITTIES PRIVATE LIMITED U64992KL2003PTC016359
$0117923$ $0003468$ ADEECR0117J M/S REVELATION AUTOMATIC PISTOLS PRIVATE LIMITED    U29300KL2011PTC020087
$0117927$ $0003472$ ADECBR9145C M/S RESSEA DOMESTIC APPLE PRIVATE LIMITED   U29208KL2004PTC010016
$0117746$ $0003291$ ADEGCR4072G M/S RANDOR MARITIME INC
```

Comment: Which part is the unique ID?

Comment: In some of the lines above, there is something like 'U29208KL2004PTC010016'. It is the unique id. Some lines are without this. Whether it is there or not, it should not come in the capture. @user1274820

Comment: Are you looking for [**`M/S(.+?)\bU\w+$`**](https://regex101.com/r/pe4bir/1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a code like this (With using LinQ):

```
var list = new[]
{
    "$0117578$ $0003123$ ADECBR5148K M/S R A MARKETING PRIVATE LIMITED",
    "$0117942$ $0003487$ ADECBR6540D M/S RICHDAUGHTER KURIES AND INVESTMENTS PVT LIMITED",
    "$0117856$ $0003401$ ADEBCR7789P M/S REGENT TRADING CO",
    "$0117881$ $0003426$ ADEBCR1123M M/S RELIANT MARKETING AND SERVICES PVT LTD  U53599KL1989PTC000007",
    "$0117896$ $0003441$ ADECBR7750D M/S GANDHIMARG CHITTIES PRIVATE LIMITED U64992KL2003PTC016359",
    "$0117923$ $0003468$ ADEECR0117J M/S REVELATION AUTOMATIC PISTOLS PRIVATE LIMITED U29300KL2011PTC020087",
    "$0117927$ $0003472$ ADECBR9145C M/S RESSEA DOMESTIC APPLE PRIVATE LIMITED U29208KL2004PTC010016",
    "$0117746$ $0003291$ ADEGCR4072G M/S RANDOR MARITIME INC"
};

// Here I use named groups to capture what I want as `A`
// Format of UniqueId here is : `U[A-Z\d]{20}`
var regex = new Regex(@"(M\/S(?<A>.+)U[A-Z\d]{20})|(M\/S(?<A>.+)$)");
var matches = (from str in list                   // loop over `list` as `str`
    select regex.Match(str)                       // create new list of values from `str`
    into match                                    // into a new variable as `match`
    where match.Groups.Count > 1                  // filter new list by `match`
    select match.Groups["A"].ToString().TrimEnd() //create new list of values again
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thnak you thank you very much. I was incorrectly thinking there was some simple regex for it. This is quite okay for me. Moreover it was quite a new learning for me from you, because I have not used LINQ. Would you please also explain how you coined the last line var matches.....I tested you code behind a button in C# and it worked fine.@hA.t

Comment: I add some explanation but I'm not good at explaining, But HTH ;).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. My doubt I ask may look silly, but that is my doubt. The regex contains two groups with its name being <A>. When the regex runs both matches. Hence the Groups.Count will be greater than 1. Then ... my doubt.... select match.Groups["A"]. This is the part I want explained at least as a comment so that I understand to learn it if I am not troubling you. Thank you.@shA.t. Your solution was beautiful.